# Rspec failure - render_template :new expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am getting the following error when I run rspec. Could really do with some help here! I am not sure if the nested resources or ajax calls are contributing to the rspec failure.

```
1) GoalsController GET #new renders the :new template
  Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template :new
    expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
  # ./spec/controllers/goals_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here are my codes as shown below.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :strategies, :only => :none do
    resources :goals
  end

  resources :goals, :only => :none do
    resources :objectives
  end
end
```

**goals_controller.rb**

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    @strategy = Strategy.find(params[:strategy_id])
  end

  def index
    @strategy = Strategy.find(params[:strategy_id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @strategy = Strategy.find(params[:strategy_id])
    @goal = @strategy.goals.create(goal_params.merge(
                                      start_date: @strategy.start_date,
                                      end_date: @strategy.end_date,
                                      created_by: @user.id))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { }
    end
  end

  private
    def goal_params
      params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :budget)
    end
end
```

**goals_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe GoalsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #new' do
    it "renders the :new template" do
      get :new, strategy_id: 2
      expect(response).to render_template :new
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: try to remove :only => :none from resources :goals, :only => :none do

Comment: Hi @Sergey, I am still getting exactly the same error. I guess `:only => :none` does not matter because the `get NEW route` I am testing is this:-
`new_strategy_goal GET    /strategies/:strategy_id/goals/new(.:format)        goals#new`

Comment: try to add render_views under RSpec.describe GoalsController, type: :controller do

Comment: Hey @SergeySokolov, I am still getting the same error after adding `render_views`. In addition, I get the following error on the browser when I go to the route directly:- 
`GoalsController#new is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []`

Comment: seems like you have no view file views/goals/new.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sergey Sokolov suggested in the comment, try removing all `:only => :none` 
in the routes.

`resources` will generate routes for all CRUD actions,`:only => :none` is basically saying you don't want it to generate at all.

Comment: Hi @Zhong-Zheng, I am still getting exactly the same error. I guess `:only => :none` does not matter because the `get NEW route` I am testing is this:-
`new_strategy_goal GET    /strategies/:strategy_id/goals/new(.:format)        goals#new`

Comment: What happen when you visit that route/page directly?

Comment: Hey @ZhongZheng I got this error when I visit the route directly
`GoalsController#new is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []`

Comment: You need to create a new template for goals model. something similar to `views/goals/new.html.erb`

Comment: Hey @ZhongZheng, I am actually rendering a partial via ajax call for this, so in console, I would be seeing something like this:-
`Started GET "/strategies/2/goals/new" for ::1 at 2017-01-18 08:26:03 +0800
Processing by GoalsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"strategy_id"=>"2"} Rendering goals/new.js.erb`
  `Rendered goals/_new.html.erb (37.5ms)
  Rendered goals/new.js.erb (52.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 101ms (Views: 80.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)`
How can I modify my rspec test in this case to ensure it is testing correctly? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it was because the request is requesting `js` format, not html.  Just put your `_new.html.erb` to `new.html.erb`. `_new.html.erb` is a partial templatelike you said, where `new.html.erb` is a view template. They are different.